# In powershell, how do you get information on all firmwares installed on your pc? Name and its version

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have the following script but I get an error when I run it.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_FirmwareDriver | Select-Object Name, Version
```

**The error:**

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "Win32_FirmwareDriver"
At line:17 char:14
+ $firmwares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_FirmwareDriver | Select-Objec ...

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: Please update your question with exception/error.

Comment: you'd have to code up something to do that. As far as I know, there isn't a single repo where all this is held, maybe `Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPSignedDriver` is what youre after?.  The error indicates the class provided is invalid, i.e., there is no such class with that name to query from or, you may have to provide the namespace first in order to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *firm*` ? returns "System Firmware 1.5.0" to me.

Or `Get-PnpDevice -Class Firmware`.

```
Status Class    FriendlyName          InstanceId
------ -----    ------------          ----------
OK     Firmware System Firmware 1.5.0 UEFI\RES_{0E978706-3BA8-4F46-B09B-9EA14E6E...
```